# Cannot connect to JRun server

Tags: coldfusion, jrun

I am just starting out with ColdFusion. I set up Apache HTTP Server, ColdFusion and ColdFusion builder, and have been able to browse through the directory structure (localhost/cfide/..., etc.), but when I try to open a .cfm file, I am given the following message

> > > Server Error
> > >
> > > The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
> > >       Could not connect to JRun Server.

I have opened the JRun management console and it is giving me the same error.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like jrun is not running.

Check your running processes, if it's not there - try starting it manually.
If that fails & it's still not there, check your error logs to see why.

[what is the environment?]

-sean

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to reconfigure my CF environment after doing a hard restart due to a system freeze (as now apache server, JRun and CFBuilder all seem to be misconfigured/missing files/unable to locate each other) and having practically no experience with any of it is really slowing me down. If I could ask, what is the relationship/interaction between JRun4 and Apache Server. Also, I am reinstalling Apache Server (since the htdocs directory is missing for some reason). Last time when I installed it I put "localhost" as both network domain and server name. Do you know if that is appropriate?

Comment: Also environment is Windows 7 Ultimate Edition

Comment: The interaction/relationship of JRun4 and Apache is really simple: an Apache module (the JRun4 connector) runs inside the Apache process and communicates with the JRun server (a different process) over a network socket. They speak some protocol, the details of which are irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! Also, do you know what the proper naming configuration for Network Domain and Server Name fields is?